# Is it safe to use JavaScript's Math.max on an array of strings?

Tags: javascript

This seems to work, on an array of strings that look like numbers (they're numbers from a CSV file read in with `csv-parse`, which seems to convert everything into strings):

```
 var a = ['123.1', '1234.0', '97.43', '5678'];
 Math.max.apply(Math, a);
```

Returns `5678`.

Does `Math.max` convert strings to numbers automatically?

Or should I do a `+` conversion myself first to be extra safe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does Math.max convert strings to numbers automatically?

Quoting the ECMA Script 5.1 Specification for [`Math.max`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.8.2.11),

> Given zero or more arguments, calls `ToNumber` on each of the arguments and returns the largest of the resulting values.

So, internally all the values are tried to convert to a number before finding the max value and you don't have to explicitly convert the strings to numbers.

But watch out for the `NaN` results if the string is not a valid number. For example, if the array had one invalid string like this

```
var a = ['123.1', '1234.0', '97.43', '5678', 'thefourtheye'];
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, a));
// NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll get a `NaN` if any of the strings aren't numbers, but otherwise it should work fine.  I'd add the `+` just to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this situation:

```
<script>
    var a=['123.1', '1234.0', '97.43', '5678','0               11111111'];
    console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, a));
</script>
```

You need to cast elements from array to be extra safe..

Answer (score 0):

if you intend to check for the max element in an array of strings using Math.max() method. you can compare the length of reach element

question: var a = ['123.1', '1234.0', '97.43', '5678'];

```
const checkLength = Math.max.apply(null, a.map(element => element.length));
```

or using spread operator for shorter form

```
const checkLength = Math.max(...a.map(element => element.length));
```

then filter to get all the elements

```
a.filter(elem => elem.length === checkLength)
```

Comment: you might consider removing the "." in each string when checking for the length. by doing something like element.split('.').join("")).length and when you do the filter